# Ceph deploy cannot create osd

Tags: ceph

I am net in ceph installation and followed some tutorials. Unluckily when I am now trying to execute the command for OSD.

```
ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/vdb node1
```

I have encountered this error

```
[ceph-vm2][INFO  ] Running command: sudo /usr/sbin/ceph-volume --cluster ceph lvm create --bluestore --data /dev/sdb
[ceph-vm2][WARNIN] -->  RuntimeError: Unable to create a new OSD id
[ceph-vm2][DEBUG ] Running command: /usr/bin/ceph-authtool --gen-print-key
[ceph-vm2][DEBUG ] Running command: /usr/bin/ceph --cluster ceph --name client.bootstrap-osd --keyring /var/lib/ceph/bootstrap-osd/ceph.keyring -i - osd new d64885d8-866c-4e26-bdda-94a6b8a79366
[ceph-vm2][DEBUG ]  stderr: [errno 1] error connecting to the cluster
[ceph-vm2][ERROR ] RuntimeError: command returned non-zero exit status: 1
[ceph_deploy.osd][ERROR ] Failed to execute command: /usr/sbin/ceph-volume --cluster ceph lvm create --bluestore --data /dev/sdb
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 OSDs
```

Comment: Did you do the preflight setup ?

Comment: yes sir. I updated the error

Answer (score 0):

Be sure your /dev/sdb got no important data first!

1.

```
#umount /dev/sdb1 or /dev/sdb2
```

2.

```
vim /etc/fstab
common /dev/sdb uuid mount
```

3.

```
#parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel gpt mkpart primary xfs 0% 100%
```

4.

```
#reboot
```

5.

```
#mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb -f
```

6.

```
ceph-deploy osd create --data /dev/sdb node1
```

Comment: Please explain the `common /dev/sdb uuid mount` command.  I am not familiar with the `common` command.

Comment: vim /etc/fstab
annotation line /dev/sdb uuid mount